# Which storage should I use to store data that is not frequented used

Tags: cloud, storage

I search for the best storage solution from a cloud hoster like digitalocean, google,aws.
Is spaces(digitalocean) or in generel S3 storage the best way if I want to build a service that uses data like a private cloud (google cloud,dropbox...).
So data is not often downloaded/uploaded but needs to be consistent. 
S3 would fit my needs but its expensive are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of two possibilities in Google Cloud Storage. First is [Nearline Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#nearline)

> Nearline Storage is a low-cost, highly durable storage service for
>   storing infrequently accessed data. Nearline Storage is a better
>   choice than Standard Storage in scenarios where slightly lower
>   availability, a 30-day minimum storage duration. ..... Nearline
>   Storage is ideal for data you plan to read or modify on average once
>   per month or less.

Minimum storage duration is 30 days.

The second option is [Coldline Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#coldline):

> Coldline Storage is a very-low-cost, highly durable storage service
>   for data archiving, online backup, and disaster recovery. Unlike other
>   "cold" storage services, your data is available within milliseconds,
>   not hours or days.
>
> Coldline Storage is the best choice for data that you plan to access
>   at most once a year, due to its slightly lower availability, 90-day
>   minimum storage duration, costs for data access, and higher
>   per-operation costs.

Full pricing table you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Answer (score 0):

I use S3 to host a few files, you can even create an static web page if you need from the properties inside the bucket.